# When joining table, rails anyway makes additional request when accessing fields from joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have companies table and cities table; company belongs to city.

Part of my db schema is:

```
  create_table "companies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title",      default: "", null: false
    t.string   "address",    default: "", null: false
    t.integer  "city_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "cities", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title",      default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "test"
  end
```

Part of `Company` model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to    :city,   :inverse_of => :companies
  # ....
end
```

Part of `City` model:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many      :companies, :inverse_of => :city
  # ....
end
```

When I fetch company, and then get its city title, it's obvious that Rails would make an additional request to fetch the city title:

```
$ rails console
2.1.5 :001 > Company.first.city.title
  Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"   ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  City Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => "My city 1"
```

And I was pretty sure I can avoid this by joining `cities` table. But I was wrong:

```
2.1.5 :002 > Company.joins(:city).first.city.title
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."id" = "companies"."city_id"  ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."id" = ? LIMIT 1      [["id", 2]]
 => "My city 1"
```

So, `cities` table was joined, but Rails anyway performs additional requests to `cities`.

Why is this, and how to avoid additional requests to `cities` table?

It doesn't hurt much when I have just one record (as in the example above), but if I want to get `Company.joins(:city).all`, and then get city of each company, then additional overhead for each fetch from `cities` is **very** significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `includes` as in `Company.includes(:city).first.city.title`.

Comment: Doesn't help. It doesn't even `JOIN` table then, and of course there are two queries. Output: http://vpaste.net/rCOYD

Comment: The way it works is by selecting all the companies in one query, and then selecting all the cities referenced by companies in another (notice the second query is now `id IN (2)` instead of `id = 2` - it means all the companies have city with id 2). If you really, REALLY want to force a single query, there is `references` method - `Company.includes(:city).references(:city)` should do that.

Comment: Ohh, great! I've tested it on `Company.includes(:city).all.each { |c| puts c.city.title }`, and it works as you explained. Thank you! By the way, it also works as a single query like this: `Company.joins(:city).includes(:city)`, but it isn't so important after your explanation.