# Left join and .includes()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, left-join

As far as I understood, the only way in Rails to perform a `LEFT JOIN` is to write SQL manually, like that:

```
Company.joins('LEFT JOIN people ON companies.id = people.company_id')
```

But then, it becomes very tricky to join other tables and use `.includes(:people)` as well.

I need to use `.includes(:people)` because otherwise Rails generates additional db request whenever I access `people` method (related question: [When joining table, rails anyway makes additional request when accessing fields from joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523326/when-joining-table-rails-anyway-makes-additional-request-when-accessing-fields))

So, this works:

```
Company.joins('LEFT JOIN people ON companies.id = people.company_id')
```

This works:

```
Company.joins('LEFT JOIN people ON companies.id = people.company_id')
      .includes(:people)
```

This works:

```
Company.joins('LEFT JOIN people ON companies.id = people.company_id')
      .includes(:people).joins(:city)
```

This **does not work**:

```
Company.joins('LEFT JOIN people ON companies.id = people.company_id')
      .includes(:people).joins(:city).includes(:city)
```

It ends up joining `people` twice, and of course db complains about ambiguous column name: `people.id`.

The generated SQL is:

```
SELECT "companies"."id" AS t0_r0, "companies"."title" AS t0_r1, 
"companies"."address" AS t0_r2, "companies"."city_id" AS t0_r3, 
"companies"."created_at" AS t0_r4, "companies"."updated_at" AS t0_r5, 
"people"."id" AS t1_r0, "people"."name" AS t1_r1, "people"."surname" AS t1_r2,
"people"."patronymic" AS t1_r3, "people"."company_id" AS t1_r4,
"people"."created_at" AS t1_r5, "people"."updated_at" AS t1_r6,
"cities"."id" AS t2_r0, "cities"."title" AS t2_r1, "cities"."created_at" AS t2_r2,
"cities"."updated_at" AS t2_r3, "cities"."test" AS t2_r4 FROM "companies" 
INNER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."id" = "companies"."city_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "people" ON "people"."company_id" = "companies"."id"
LEFT JOIN people ON companies.id = people.company_id
```

My understanding is that when we write `JOIN` SQL code manually, Rails has no control of it and it can't figure out that `people` table is already joined.

If I write it like this, it works:

```
Company.joins(:people).includes(:people).joins(:city).includes(:city)
```

But then, it uses `INNER JOIN`, but I need for `LEFT JOIN`. I still can't find the way to use `LEFT JOIN` so that this is under control of Rails.

How to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it: we need to use `.references()` in conjunction with `.includes`; then, Rails performs `LEFT JOIN` and we can reference joined table in SQL query.

So, this works:

```
Company.includes(:people).references(:people).includes(:city).references(:city)
```

Well, this seems messy area.

Comment: It's cleaner to group the join and reference tables to an array, syntax goes like this Company.includes([:people, :city]).references([:people, :city])

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `Company.joins(:people, :city).select("*")`.
Assuming Company has direct association to People and City both.

This is even possible with indirect relations. For instance Company "has_many" People and City. Then, City "has_many" Views.
`Company.joins(:people, city: :views).select("*")`

If there are two nested relations to inner join with. Lets add one more relation with City. City "has_many" Views & Whales.

`Company.joins(:people, city: [:views, :whales]).select("*")`

Comment: You might want to [edit], add an explanation and try for [answer]. I recommend to rethink your decision not to take the recommended [tour].